# Orchard CMS can't find scripts or styles

Tags: webmatrix, orchardcms-1.8

I have prepared an Orchard based website locally, using WebMatrix. I then published to my hosting provider.

However the deployed version isn't picking up the styles or scripts, either my theme or for the dashboard, and it's giving me 404 errors.

I guess I have to change the path somewhere to get it to pick up the files, can anyone tell me where? or is there a different solution?

[image: example of 404 errors]

Answer (score 2):

I thought that this would be a setting on the website, but as it turns out it was an IIS setting.

I switched the pipeline mode from Classic to Integrated, and everything worked.